# When did LEGO stop using perforated plastic bags and switched to simple ones?

Tags: manufacturing, packaging

I'm talking about those sophisticated bags used to pack the contents of the sets in 90's.
Here is an illustration of such bag:

[image: Perforated plastic bag]

Could anyone tell when LEGO started to pack the majority of their sets into simple bags instead of perforated ones?

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK TLG still uses these bags, and they are not unique to the 90ies. They are used for accessory bags, such as the one in your picture, or other various accessories such as these that came in the 2013 Friends Advent Calendar:

https://store.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=41016-11

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I didn't know that. However, I shall probably update my question because I implied usual sets, vast majority of which used to be packed in those perforated bags.

Comment: Now they are about to get rid of plastic bags altogether in favor of paper. https://www.bbc.com/news/business-54169686